# gamesalad to unity3D?

Tags: objective-c, unity-game-engine, cocos2d-x, gamesalad

I'm a newer than new newbie ... and I think this question should be part of the thread [Newbie - Game Development (iPhone) - New to Objective C and Game Dev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259261/newbie-game-development-iphone-new-to-objective-c-and-game-dev) but I could only find an "answer" post window. I'd like to ask a related question.

If I were to develop a game in GameSalad or Stencyl, would I be able to look at the actual code of that creation and maybe import it into something more complicated like Cocos2d-x or Unity3D later on?

I ask, because happybadgers advised in that above mentioned question/answer to start out in something like GameSalad -- sort of jump into creating a game while learning objective c. But I imagine a person would eventually want to do more than "drag and drop" coding as their skills increased ... so -- could you take your drag and drop creation(s) and pop it/them into something that lets you play with the code more?

I'm aware that this may be a stupid, naive or stupidly naive question, so please excuse me, if so.

Thank you for your time. And if you vote to boot this question, I hope you'll explain the error of my ways.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you cannot view the code directly in Gamesalad. However, a lot of the logic behind the game will be easy to replicate in code once you get the hang of it.

An example of this is the statements that you use such as if, while, for, get and set will all be available in Unityscript. You will not be able to convert your game into a Unity file however the art assets will be transferable.(So basically you can keep the aesthetic of your game,but you will just need to translate the drag and drop to code.)

Good luck,

p.s
(If you are really struggling with some code, just send me the drag and drop logic and I will do my best to convert it for you).